# How to detect when an AVPlayerItem is finished playing?

Tags: ios, avplayer

I've been looking through the `AVPlayerItem` and `AVPlayer` docs and there doesn't seem to be any callbacks for when the item is finished playing. I was hoping that there would be some sort of delegate callback that we can utilize or that `AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd` would provide a custom action for us to write.

How can i figure out a way to detect when AVPlayer has finished playing an item?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57980323/294884

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It uses `NSNotification` to alert when playback is finished.

Register for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];
```

Method to call when done:

```
-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *) notification {
    // Will be called when AVPlayer finishes playing playerItem
}
```

Comment: you can use `[avPlayer currentItem]` if you use AVPlayerViewController

Comment: can i observe the track name for updating my UI ?

Answer (score 7):

Swift-i-fied (version 3)

```
class MyVideoPlayingViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyVideo", 
                                                                  ofType: "mp4")!)
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(MyVideoPlayingViewController.animationDidFinish(_:)),
                                           name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: player?.currentItem)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        player?.play()
    }

    func animationDidFinish(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Animation did finish")
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer but be sure to invoke removeObserver(_:name:object:) before observer or any object specified in addObserver:selector:name:object: is deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:player.currentItem];


- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
   // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```